# Clojure- Amending code for different functionality

Tags: clojure, hive, impala

This line of code:

```
dates (distinct (map (keyword :cobdate) data))
```

had to be amended to this line of code

```
dates (distinct (map #(get % "cobdate") data))
```

in order to use in the way I required

Could anyone tell me how to convert this line of code:

```
grouped-by-token (group-by :severity data)
```

in order to make the same conversion?

Comment: You cannot make the same conversion because that line of code doesn't do the same thing as what was changed in the other line. You might find help more easily if you provided an example of the data that the line should work on.

Comment: FWIW, your first line could be modified to `(distinct (map :cobdate data))`, it would accomplish the same thing as the second snippet. Typically `get` is used as such: `(get data "cobdate" value-if-cobdate-missing)`. This allows you to avoid `nil` and null pointer exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to [`group-by`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/group-by) is a function. `:severity`, in your third sample, is being used as a function, because keywords can be treated as functions: `(:severity {:severity 1}) ;; => 1`.

Because strings cannot be treated as functions, you must use the alternate syntax to extract the value.

```
grouped-by-token (group-by #(% "severity") data)
```